# Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, time-series, sentinel-1

I know there are many posts abbout this but for some reason those solutions doesn't work for my code.

I'm trying to create timeseries for an imagecollection which was created using image expressiones.

I have tried to use

```
.copyProperties(im,['system:time_start']);
```

but didn't work and still got error message.

This is how I tried to keep the time properties in my code:

```
var FrostDB=clippedSAR.map(function(im){ 
   im = Frost(ee.Image(im),frostDamp,ksize);
   return im;
});



print(FrostDB);

var model=FrostDB.map(function(im){ 

  var nrpb = im.expression(
    'VH - VV / (VH + VV)', {
      'VH': im.select('VH_sum'),
      'VV': im.select('VV_sum')
    }).rename('NRPB').copyProperties(im,['system:time_start']);


  // adding NPRB Band to the original Image
  var withNRPB = im.addBands(nrpb);

  var result = withNRPB.expression(
      '2.572-(-0.05047*VH)+(0.17*VV)+(3.422*NRPB)', {
      'VH': withNRPB.select('VH_sum'),
      'VV': withNRPB.select('VV_sum'),
      'NRPB': withNRPB.select('NRPB').copyProperties(im,['system:time_start'])
    });


  // Only returning result band (other bands are not returned
  // you can add the result just like the nprb band was added if you want to return everything)
  return(result.copyProperties(im,['system:time_start']));
});


print('model:',model);

print(ui.Chart.image.series(model, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10));
```

**My end goal:
To create time series without getting this error message.**

edit: link to my code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/4acde71b4b34093ac61cb76efe6a7339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not reproducible, but I always use this to copy all properties from an old image to a new one:

```
NEWIMAGE = NEWIMAGE.set(OLDIMAGE.toDictionary(OLDIMAGE.propertyNames()));
```

Change this in BOTH of your functions:

1)

```
var FrostDB=clippedSAR.map(function(OLDIMAGE){ 
   var NEWIMAGE = Frost(ee.Image(OLDIMAGE),frostDamp,ksize);
   return NEWIMAGE.set(OLDIMAGE.toDictionary(OLDIMAGE.propertyNames()));
});
```

2)

```
return result.set(im.toDictionary(im.propertyNames()));
```

Comment: @Kulik unfortunatly didn't work, I have edit the original post with link to the code

Comment: see updated answer: the error is you don't set the system time property in the first function